# Emacs: How to show the current directory in the frame bar?

Tags: emacs, customization

When opening a file in Emacs on Mac OS X, the file's path is displayed in the window bar (this bar at the upper end of the window which contains the three buttons for quitting, maximizing and minimizing). If I have a shell open (<kbd>C-c s</kbd>), it only displays `*shell*` -- not very useful, especially if there are multiple shells open. How can I display the path of the current working directory in the window bar? So, for example, `/ssh:mylogin@mymachine.foo.bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq frame-title-format '((:eval default-directory)))
```

Comment: ... then it only shows \*invalid\*. But I found the following in my .emacs:
    `(setq frame-title-format
      '(:eval (if (buffer-file-name) (abbreviate-file-name (buffer-file-name)) "%b")))`
Do you know how to adjust this?

Comment: It works, thanks. Is it possible to have the path to the home directory abbreviated? It's somehow strange: if I have .emacs open, I see "~/" in the title bar; and if I have a file in "~/some/where" open, I see "/Users/myuser/some/where/" so the *full* path... Another thing: How can the buffername/filename be included?

Comment: so, basically `(setq frame-title-format '(:eval (if (buffer-file-name) (abbreviate-file-name (buffer-file-name)) "%b")))` does very well what I would like to have, but (with tramp) on a remote server, it shows `/ssh:myuser@host.foo.bar:/very/long/path/to/the/home/dir/-shell` instead of something like `/ssh:myuser@host.foo.bar:~`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Where/in what context do you have to execute this?   Using emacs 24, executing this command either in .emacs, or explicitly in the minibuffer, nothing happens.